# Adding boost library to cocos2d-x project in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, cocos2d-x

I've stumbled upon a problem trying to build a cross-platform app using cocos2d-x. Currently I'm trying to build for Mac OSX. I've tried linking to the boost header files but I keep getting errors stating boost/shared_ptr.hpp cannot be found. I'm only using the smart pointer headers.

I've added the root boost directory to Header Search Paths: $(SRCROOT)/../../boost_1_55_0 (non-recursive)
and the libs directory to Library Search Paths: $(SRCROOT)/../../boost_1_55_0/libs (non-recursive)

- I tried this for both the root project file and cocos2d_libs project file with no good results.
- I also tried adding to User Header Search Paths.

I've added them successfully on an SFML project, so does cocos2d-x bypass these search paths?

Thanks to anyone who is willing to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have missed some step in your setup. Have a double check on every detail as you can go through these guidelines:

- [Porting a Cocos2d-x iOS game to Android](http://blog.codetactics.com/2013/06/05/porting-a-cocos2d-x-ios-game-to-android/)
- [How to create a multi-platform project in one command line](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi-platform_project_in_one_command_line)

This should help, as attention to detail if worthwhile.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really help me. I'm not even considering android yet, and I've already created a multi-platform project through the command line. The initial project runs fine, until I try adding in the boost library.

Answer (score 1):

I never figured out the problem, but I realise now that there's no need to even use boost. Cocos2d-x is compatible with C++11. What a relief.

Answer (score 1):

Since XCode builds Cocos2DX projects for Mac and iOS you need to setup header search paths independently. Just switch target in XCode from iOS to Mac and set path to Boost for Mac build. Should work.